# Haskell OpenCL package on Win64 2014.2.0.0 Crashes

Tags: haskell, opencl, cabal, haskell-platform

I just upgraded my Haskell Platform to the latest (*64-bit* 2014.2.0.0) from an older one (*32-bit* 2013.2.0.0).  I reinstalled various packages that my project requires via cabal and built the main.  However, this time around the [OpenCL (1.0.3.4)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenCL-1.0.3.4) package crashes in the first foreign call it makes (`clGetPlatformIDs`).

- The crash is an access violation.
- I can't get a stack trace through any of the Windows debugging tools.
- I set a breakpoint in Visual Studio in `clGetPlatformIDs` which never hits, so the crash precedes that.  I don't have symbols for `OpenCL.dll`, but I think it should be able to find the interface symbol; it resolved the breakpoint.
- The KHR `OpenCL.dll` does get loaded.
- None of the registers contain a usable address which lands in a module that I can see.
- I can get further through `ghci`.  The calls work, but my OpenCL implementation doesn't show up.
- The 32-bit platform works fine.

This sort smells like a linking issue. (I am not getting out of the Haskell runtime cleanly.) **How can I fix this or debug it?  How does one generally debug binding issues like this?**

NOTE 1: upon re-installation of various packages I see warnings like:

```
  Util.hs:291:1: Warning:
      the 'stdcall' calling convention is unsupported on this platform,
      treating as ccall
      When checking declaration:
        foreign import stdcall unsafe "static windows.h GetCurrentProcessId" getCurrentProcessId
        :: IO WIN32.DWORD
```

I ignored these as they appear in great quantities for packages that function correctly.  Minimal testing shows that they still work, and I couldn't find anything significant online about this warning.  Win32 API is heavily used in Haskell, and I don't believe that it's totally broken on 64-bit Haskell Platform.  Moreover, the above `getCurrentProcessId` works fine.  I am assuming `ghc` picks the right convention for x64 and ignores stdcall (which I think doesn't exist on Windows).

NOTE 2: I installed the OpenCL module with the following command:

```
% cabal install OpenCL \
    --extra-include-dirs="C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\4.0\include" \
    --extra-lib-dirs="C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\4.0\lib\x64"
```

(The \ newlines are inserted here for readability; this was one line.)